# Simplify the following expression for small x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$ \dfrac{\left(x+1\right)^2}{x^2\left(2x+1\right)}-\dfrac{\left(x+1\right)\ln\left(2x+1\right)}{x^3} $$

How to simplify the above expression for small $x$? I'm having trouble with $x^2$ and $x^3$ in the denominators. The other factors, I can Taylor expand but what to do with $x^2$ and $x^3$? The end result should be a simple expression like $a+bx+cx^2$. Hints are also fine :)

Comment: It seems $x=0$ is a singularity. You get a Laurent series. See [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+%5Cdfrac%7B%5Cleft(x%2B1%5Cright)%5E2%7D%7Bx%5E2%5Cleft(2x%2B1%5Cright)%7D-%5Cdfrac%7B%5Cleft(x%2B1%5Cright)%5Cln%5Cleft(2x%2B1%5Cright)%7D%7Bx%5E3%7D+near+x%3D0).

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing a factor $2$ in the first summand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For $|x| \ll 1$, we have

$$ \ln(1 + 2x) \approx 2x - 8x^3 + O(x^5) $$
$$ \frac{1}{1+2x} \approx 1 - 2x + 4x^2 + O(x^3) $$

Apply these approximations to your function. You'll still have a factor of $1/x^2$ in both terms. A simple polynomial approximation doesn't exist.